# Autodesk Forge How to get dbid from name

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I have an extension which loads a docking panel with a text field and a button. The functionality of this button would be to display the DB-ID of the item name given in the text field.

Something like:
Rubber = 2130

where Rubber is the input and 2130(db-id) will be the output

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using `.search()` method, which is a supported way:

```
viewer.search('Rubber', function(dbIds){
  // here the dbIds is a list of dbIds, you can handle it
  callback(dbIds); // handle the results async
}, function(error){
  // handle errors here...
}, ['name'] /* this array indicates the filter: search only on 'Name'*/
)
```

And look here on [how to improve performance](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/search-method-performance) on search.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just for readability, could you bring the final `)` bracket either before the last comment or on a new line

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API available currently, but a workaround can be used in this case. It's shown as the following:

```
//-- For the element type or element category like "Floor [" or "Floor"

var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
var strIdx = it.nodeAccess.strings.indexOf( "Floor [" );
// var strIdx = it.nodeAccess.strings.indexOf( "Floor" );
var nameIdx = it.nodeAccess.names.indexOf( strIdx );
for( var key in it.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex ) {
  if( it.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex[key] === nameIdx ) console.log( key )
}


//-- For element name like "Floor[766598]":
var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
var eidIndex = it.nodeAccess.nameSuffixes.indexOf( 766598 );
for( let key in it.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex ) { 
  if( it.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex[key] === eidIndex ) console.log( key ) 
}
```

**P.S. Since this is just a workaround, not the formal solution. You would have to use it at your own risk.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using the `search()` method, you could also create your own Object that maps the name to ID's. This is a temporary workaround until Autodesk implements its own method.

```
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree; // Get model tree
var allDbIds = Object.keys(instanceTree.nodeAccess.names); //get array of all ID's
var forgeNameMap = {} //Empty array for mapping names
allDbIds.map(function(id) { 
    forgeNameMap[instanceTree.getNodeName(id)] = id
})

let rubberID = forgeNameMap["Rubber"]
```